# Subgroup summation with missing value in R

Tags: r

I have am trying to calculate simple Herfindahl index by 
market Share(1)^2+market Share (2)^2 (ignoring the NA but using it to calculate the market share). I tried several ways but is still included in my final HI calculation.

My data

```
df = data.frame(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L), 
            ID_name = c("AA", "AA", "", "BB", "BB", "", "", "DD", "DD"), 
            Volume = c(10L, 20L, 30L, 50L, 50L, 40L, 20L, 30L, 10L))
```

I tried

```
    df%>%
  mutate(Hasparent_org_id = ifelse(is.na(ID_name), 0, 1)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(sum_TRx = sum(Volume),HHI =sum(((Volume/sum(Volume))^2)*Hasparent_org_id))
```

- And i get this

  > ```
  > ID MKT_Vol       HHI   (int)   (int)     (dbl) 1     1      60 0.3888889 2     2     140 0.3367347 3     4      60 0.3888889
  > ```

But i want to get this

```
bf = data.frame(ID = c(1L, 2L,  4L), 
            Volume = c(60L, 140L, 60L),
            HHI = c(0.14,0.25, 0.26 ))
```

Basically, include volume corresponding the NA entries to calculate the market share, but not include it in HI calculations.

Comment: Your blank entries in ID_name aren't NA values, they are empty strings. Either explicitly use NA when creating the data.frame or use ID_name == "" in the ifelse().

Comment: Thank you, Ian! That was really easy fix thanks to your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in your `is.na` check.  There are *no* `NA` values in `Hasparent_org_id` - you have some empty strings `""` instead.

```
df%>%
  mutate(Hasparent_org_id = ifelse(ID_name=="", 0, 1)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(sum_TRx = sum(Volume),HHI =sum(((Volume/sum(Volume))^2)*Hasparent_org_id))
```

This change in the check seems to address your issue.

Comment: Thanks Mark! This is precisely what i needed. Thank you for your help! It works now, yeahhh!